# Passing the twitter search json response to a flask route that outputs json

Tags: python, json, twitter, python-twitter

I am using the python library [python-twitter](https://github.com/bear/python-twitter) to access the twitter api.

I am doing a search query and want that response to go my flask route.

I get this erro

```
TypeError: <twitter.status.Status object at 0x7f16dc089110> is not JSON serializable
```

Here is what I have

```
@app.route('/t/search/tweets',  methods=['GET'])
def twit():
    results = twitter_api.GetSearch(count=count, term='hello world')
    return Response(json.dumps(results),  mimetype='application/json')
```

Here is the full trackback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/john/.virtualenvs/in5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/john/.virtualenvs/in5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/home/john/.virtualenvs/in5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 110, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/home/john/.virtualenvs/in5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/john/.virtualenvs/in5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/john/.virtualenvs/in5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/john/.virtualenvs/in5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 110, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/home/john/.virtualenvs/in5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/john/.virtualenvs/in5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/john/.virtualenvs/in5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/john/Scripts/Python/in5/views.py", line 73, in twit
    return Response(json.dumps(results),  mimetype='application/json')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 243, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 207, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 184, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: <twitter.status.Status object at 0x7fc3d3384390> is not JSON serializable
```

And here is the 'print results'

```
[<twitter.status.Status object at 0x7ff1f3114f90>, <twitter.status.Status object at 0x7ff1f30c6050>, <twitter.status.Status object at 0x7ff1f30c6190>, <twitter.status.Status object at 0x7ff1f30c6310>, <twitter.status.Status object at 0x7ff1f30c6510>, <twitter.status.Status object at 0x7ff1f30c65d0>, <twitter.status.Status object at 0x7ff1f30c6690>, <twitter.status.Status object at 0x7ff1f30c67d0>, <twitter.status.Status object at 0x7ff1f30c69d0>, <twitter.status.Status object at 0x7ff1f30c6c10>, <twitter.status.Status object at 0x7ff1f30c6d90>, <twitter.status.Status object at 0x7ff1f30c6e50>, <twitter.status.Status object at 0x7ff1f30c90d0>, <twitter.status.Status object at 0x7ff1f30c91d0>, <twitter.status.Status object at 0x7ff1f30c9290>, <twitter.status.Status object at 0x7ff1f30c9410>, <twitter.status.Status object at 0x7ff1f30c95d0>, <twitter.status.Status object at 0x7ff1f30c9690>, <twitter.status.Status object at 0x7ff1f30c9750>, <twitter.status.Status object at 0x7ff1f30c9a10>, <twitter.status.Status object at 0x7ff1f30c9ad0>, <twitter.status.Status object at 0x7ff1f30c9c10>, <twitter.status.Status object at 0x7ff1f30c9dd0>, <twitter.status.Status object at 0x7ff1f30c9e90>, <twitter.status.Status object at 0x7ff1f30c9f90>, <twitter.status.Status object at 0x7ff1f30cf1d0>, <twitter.status.Status object at 0x7ff1f30cf290>, <twitter.status.Status object at 0x7ff1f30cf510>, <twitter.status.Status object at 0x7ff1f30cf5d0>, <twitter.status.Status object at 0x7ff1f30cf690>, <twitter.status.Status object at 0x7ff1f30cf810>, <twitter.status.Status object at 0x7ff1f30cf8d0>, <twitter.status.Status object at 0x7ff1f30cfa50>, <twitter.status.Status object at 0x7ff1f30cfc90>, <twitter.status.Status object at 0x7ff1f30cfed0>, <twitter.status.Status object at 0x7ff1f30cff90>, <twitter.status.Status object at 0x7ff1f30d6090>, <twitter.status.Status object at 0x7ff1f30d6210>, <twitter.status.Status object at 0x7ff1f30d6390>, <twitter.status.Status object at 0x7ff1f30d6590>, <twitter.status.Status object at 0x7ff1f30d66d0>, <twitter.status.Status object at 0x7ff1f30d6890>, <twitter.status.Status object at 0x7ff1f30d6990>, <twitter.status.Status object at 0x7ff1f30d6a10>, <twitter.status.Status object at 0x7ff1f30d6a90>, <twitter.status.Status object at 0x7ff1f30d6bd0>, <twitter.status.Status object at 0x7ff1f30d6c90>, <twitter.status.Status object at 0x7ff1f30d6e50>, <twitter.status.Status object at 0x7ff1f30dc050>, <twitter.status.Status object at 0x7ff1f30dc110>]
```

Comment: what's the results ? show us the data

Comment: i mean `results` variable.

Comment: see how it a list of twitter status objects? python is telling you that you cannot turn those into json

Comment: but what I don't understand is the fact that I am getting a json back from the api.  And some where along the lines python is making it a list instead of a json

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88796/discussion-between-taesu-and-interneteur).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: how to make a class JSON serializable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895/python-how-to-make-a-class-json-serializable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to dig their source code and it turns out you have to use `AsDict()`

```
json_results = [result.AsDict() for result in results]
```

such a pain...

I firmly recommend using [tweepy](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy) instead of this lib for the lack of documentation.

Comment: but on the [dev docs](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets) it says application json

Comment: can you just paste what `results` looks like?

Comment: TypeError: <twitter.status.Status object at 0x7f4c96d48cd0> is not JSON serializable

Comment: after changing the url no change, still same errors

Comment: can you print out what those twitter objects really are? `for result in results: print result`

Answer (score 0):

Obviously  python-twitter already deserializes the api call results into a custom twitter.status.Status object (or a list of). By default, `json.dump()` know only about basic types (strings, numerics, lists and dicts), so you have to provide your own encoder for anything else, as explained here : https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#encoders-and-decoders

You may also want to read this: [How to make a class JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895/python-how-to-make-a-class-json-serializable)

Comment: you can use `instance.AsDict()`. apparently it's not written anywhere in their doc. (I don't even think they have their own doc...)